# SQL Server 2017. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Q'

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2017, python-packaging

I am trying to install a locally built Python library and install it on SQL server. I have managed to make the wheel file using `setuptools` and install it on the sql server. The wheel set up looks like this.

```
import setuptools
 
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
 
setuptools.setup(
    name="Q",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Ben Watson",
    author_email="ben.watson@XXXXX.com",
    description="Package for SQL server that .....",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license_files = ('LICENSE.txt',),
    #packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7.1",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7.1',
)
```

I can see that the install worked. Tested this and get the following output.

`STDOUT message(s) from external script:  Package Q is version 0.0.1`

I now try and run the code as such;

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
  @language = N'Python',
  @script = N'
import Q as Qtest

x=Qtest.test()
print(x)

'
```

The issue is that locally running the file throws the error;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Q'
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Most of the help online point to a path issue. SQL Server has specific requirements for the path, so I am reluctant to alter this in any way.

Regards

Ben

Comment: SQL Server keeps its own, separate, installations of Python and R. Are you adding the module into SQL Server's Python installation, or a different installation of Python that's shared amongst other users and processes on the Windows server?

Comment: I am adding to the SQL server python instalations to be used by the SQL server. I have done this with other packages. The only difference here is python wheel is one that I have created.